# Duplicated output with for each loop

Tags: perl

My code loops through multiple files in a directory, parses each file and appends the parsed content of each file to `FinalVariantfile.txt`.

The code works, but duplicates the content of each file.

When I ran the code with two files the output contained 4 files. Could someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix this?

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

    use strict;

    #directory structure

    my $home         = "/data/";
    my $tsvdirectory = $home . "test_all_runs/" . $ARGV[0];
    my $tsvfiles     = $home . "test_all_runs/" . $ARGV[0] . "/tsv_files.txt";

    my $FinalVariants = $home . "test_all_runs/" . $ARGV[0] . "/FinalVariantfile.txt";

    my @tsvfiles        = ();
    my @currentlines    = ();
    my $currentline     = '';
    my $currentCNVline  = '';
    my @currentCNVlines = ();
    my @HotSpotLines    = ();
    my @CNVLines        = ();

    # command to produce the vcf_files.txt file stored in each individual run
    # directory; the file list includes solely vcf files which have not been
    # previously prepared and/or annotated
    my $cmd = `ls $tsvdirectory/FOCUS*\.tsv > $tsvfiles`;

    # print "$cmd";
    my $cmda = "ls $tsvdirectory/FOCUS*\.tsv > $tsvfiles";

    # print "$cmda";

    # this code opens the vcf_files.txt file and passes each line into an array for
    # indidivudal manipulation
    open( TXT2, "$tsvfiles" );
    while ( <TXT2> ) {
        push( @tsvfiles, $_ );
    }
    close(TXT2);

    foreach ( @tsvfiles ) {
        chop($_);
    }

    # this code then parses each of the files listed by name in the tsvfiles array
    foreach ( @tsvfiles ) {

        my $currenttsvfile = "$_";    # establishes the current file being manipulated

        my $MDLfinaltsvfile = $currenttsvfile;
        $MDLfinaltsvfile =~ s/\.tsv/_prepared\.txt/g;

        # this series of variable calls names the various intermediate or
        # final output files

        my $MDLlinestsvfile = $currenttsvfile;
        $MDLlinestsvfile =~ s/\.tsv/_withCNV\.txt/g;

        my $Variantlinestsvfile = $currenttsvfile;
        $Variantlinestsvfile =~ s/\.tsv/_HotSpot\.txt/g;

        my $MDLtsvfile = $currenttsvfile;
        $MDLtsvfile =~ s/\.tsv/_FilteredAllcolumns\.txt/g;

        my $MDLsampleid = $currenttsvfile;
        $MDLsampleid =~ s/\-oncogene.tsv//g;
        print "The currentVCFis############# " . $currenttsvfile . "\n";

        my @SampleID = ();
        @SampleID = split /\//, $MDLsampleid;
        print "The sampleIDis##############" . $SampleID[4] . "\n";

        my $CNVdata = $currenttsvfile;
        $CNVdata =~ s/\.tsv/_cnv\.txt/g;

        my $FinalCNVdata = $currenttsvfile;
        $FinalCNVdata =~ s/\.tsv/_finalcnv\.txt/g;

        my $cmd2 = `fgrep -v "#" $currenttsvfile > $MDLlinestsvfile`;
        print "$cmd2";    # this code extracts from the current vcf file all of the
                          # lines of data and outputs them into a separate file

        my $cmd5 = `grep -vwE "(CNV|intronic|synonymous|utr_3|utr_5)" 
#removes lines that contain CNV/intronic/synonymous/utr_3/utr_5"

$MDLlinestsvfile > $Variantlinestsvfile`;
        print "$cmd5";

        open( my $fh_in, '<', $Variantlinestsvfile )
                or die "cannot open $Variantlinestsvfile: $!\n"; 
#removes lines that contain 0/0 and ./. genotypes from field 70.

        open( my $fh_out, '>', $MDLtsvfile )
                or die "cannot open $MDLtsvfile: $!\n";

        while ( my $line = <$fh_in> ) {

            # tab/field-based:
            my @fields = split( /\s+/, $line );
            print $fh_out $line unless ( $fields[70] =~ m|([0.])/\1| );
        }
        close($fh_in);
        close($fh_out);

        #open each filtered file with all columns and pushes it into array.
        open( TXT2, "$MDLtsvfile" );
        while (<TXT2>) {
            push( @HotSpotLines, $_ );
        }
        close(TXT2);

        foreach (@HotSpotLines) {
            chop($_);

            my @HotSpotEntries = ();
            my $currentMDLline = $_;
            @HotSpotEntries = split( /\t/, $currentMDLline );

            my $chr        = $HotSpotEntries[9];
            my $position   = $HotSpotEntries[10];
            my $cosmicids  = $HotSpotEntries[21];
            my $refforward = $HotSpotEntries[67];
            my $genotype   = $HotSpotEntries[70];
            my $altforward = $HotSpotEntries[77];
            my $altreverse = $HotSpotEntries[78];
            my $cDNA       = $HotSpotEntries[81];
            my $exon       = $HotSpotEntries[83];
            my $conseq     = $HotSpotEntries[84];
            my $location   = $HotSpotEntries[88];
            my $geneclass  = $HotSpotEntries[92];
            my $aachange   = $HotSpotEntries[98];
            my $transcript = $HotSpotEntries[100];

            $currentline
                    = $SampleID[4] . "\t"
                    . $chr . "\t"
                    . $position . "\t"
                    . $cosmicids . "\t"
                    . $refforward . "\t"
                    . $refreverse . "\t"
                    . $genotype . "\t"
                    . $altforward . "\t"
                    . $altreverse . "\t"
                    . $cDNA . "\t"
                    . $exon . "\t"
                    . $conseq . "\t"
                    . $location . "\t"
                    . $geneclass . "\t"
                    . $aachange . "\t"
                    . $transcript;

            # print "The currentVCFlineis ".$currentline."\n";
            push( @currentlines, $currentline );

        }

        my $i;

        for ( $i = 0; $i < @currentlines; $i += 1 ) {

            my $currentguiline = $currentlines[$i];

            my $cmd5 = `echo "$currentguiline" >> $FinalVariants`;
            print "$cmd5";

            #my $cmd9 = `sed -i '1i$SampleID[4]' $FinalVariants`; print $cmd9;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the contents of `@tsvfiles` after the `ls` command.  This code seems overly complex and hard to follow for what it appears to be doing.

Comment: `ls` lists the path to tsv files and outputs it in a tsv_files.txt. Each file is only listed once, therefore, I don't undestand why it somehow loops through each file twice? All I'm doing is listing path to files of interest, looping through each file, parsing it and dumping into FinalVariantfile.txt. I'm happy to learn another way of accomplishing the same, however, I try to say away from comlex regular expressions since I'm a novice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to start so many new shell subprocesses to do such basic operations. `ls`, `fgrep`, `grep` and `echo` all have equivalents in Perl, and especially calling `echo` for each line of text is a very poor way of copying one file to another

I suspect that your problem is because of the line

```
my $cmd5 = `echo "$currentguiline" >> $FinalVariants`;
```

which will *append* each element of `@currentlines` to the end of the file. So the first time you run your program it will contain a single copy of the result, but every subsequent run will just add more data to the end of your file and it will keep growing

I hate to offer a hack to get things working, but it would take me ages to understand what your program is doing behind all the confusion and write a proper concise version. You can fix it temporarily by adding the line

```
unlink $FinalVariants or die $!;
```

before the `foreach ( @tsvfiles ) { ... }` loop. This will delete the file and ensure that a new version is created for each execution of your program.

---

Okay, I've studied your code carefully and I *think* this will do what you intend. Without any data or even file name samples I've been unable to test it beyond making sure that it compiles, so it will be a miracle if it works first time, but I believe it's the best chance you have of getting a coherent solution

Note that there's a problem with `$refreverse` that you use in your own code but never declare or define it, so there's no way that the code you show will create the problem you say it does because it dies during compilation with the error message

```
Global symbol "$refreverse" requires explicit package name
```

I've guessed that it's right after `$ref_forward` at index 68

Please report back about how well this functions

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $home          = "/data";
my $tsv_directory = "$home/test_all_runs/$ARGV[0]";

my $final_variants = "$tsv_directory/final_variant_file.txt";

open my $out_fh, '>', $final_variants
        or die qq{Unable to open "$final_variants" for output: $!};

my @tsv_files = glob "$tsv_directory/FOCUS*.tsv";

for my $tsv_file ( @tsv_files ) {

    print "The current VCF is ############# $tsv_file\n";

    $tsv_file =~ m|([^/]+)-oncogene.tsv$| or die "Cant extract Sample ID";
    my $sample_id = $1;
    print "The sample ID is ############## $sample_id\n";

    open my $in_fh, '<', $tsv_file
            or die qq{Unable to open "$tsv_file" for input: $!};

    while ( <$in_fh> ) {

        next if /^#/;
        next if /\b(?:CNV|intronic|synonymous|utr_3|utr_5)\b/;

        my @fields = split;
        next if $fields[70] eq '0/0' or $fields[70] eq './.';

        my @wanted = ( 9, 10, 21, 67, 68, 70, 77, 78, 81, 83, 84, 88, 92, 98, 100 );
        my $current_line = join "\t", @fields[@wanted];

        print $out_fh $current_line, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part is confusing? I delete $FinalVariants file each time I run the code.

Comment: @user3781528: The main problem is that you use such a vast number of different variables and temporary files that what's actually going on is obfuscated. I've sure it's something very simple really

Comment: I don't think the problem is echo.  I've tried a different method add it produced the same result. I can't test until tomorrow. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I really like how concise your code is and it works great.  With few adjustments it ran great. 
`I had to change next if $fields[70] eq '0/0' or $fields[70] eq './.'; to next if ($fields[70] =~ m|([0.])/\1|);`
Could you please suggest how to add $sample_id as the first column of the output and also how to remove the header row from each .tsv file so that the output doesn’t contain any header rows? Thanks

Comment: @user3781528: It works? I'm astonished! I'm sorry about the check on `$fields[70]`: your own comment says *"removes lines that contain `0/0` and `./.` genotypes from field 70"*, and I assumed it should be *equality* from other, similar answers I have written. I think it should be `next if $fields[70] =~ m{\./\.|0/0}` as the back-reference only confuses here, and I've changed my answer. I'm sorry that I forgot to add `$sample_id` to the output. I've also made a change for that

Comment: @user3781528: As for removing header rows, your question *still* doesn't show any real data. I would normally say that you should open another question, but I don't think much harm is done if you just amend your question to show what we're dealing with. Please include the output of `ls /data/test_all_runs/$ARGV[0]` as well as the contents of a couple of data files

Comment: how do I attach files here?

Comment: @user3781528: I hope you will absorb how there's no need for multiple intermediate files if you're using Perl? You should also drop the habit of declaring a bunch of variables at the top of your program -- that is (very old) C-style programming, and it's not appropriate in most modern languages. Variables should always be declared *as late as possible*. You should adopt `snake_case` instead of `CamelCase` wherever possible. Capital letters imply global variables, and `lower_case_names_remain_readable`, especially for people whose native language isn't English

Comment: @user3781528: It is best to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37978686/edit) -- the link is on the left, right above the comments on your question. If you want to post more than fifty or so lines then you can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and put a link here, but it's always best to avoid out-of-band links if you can. Stack Overflow questions never die, but your references may well be deleted.

Comment: Sorry, one last related question.   It possible to edit values in columns of interest (e.g  21, 67) before I collect them in @wanted? I will post data soon. Thanks

Comment: @user3781528: Do you understand most of what I have written? The proper way would be to use the header names that you want to remove to identify the columns that you want to keep, as well as those that you want to change. I hope that you should be able to make a stab at that yourself. It sounds like you should save your edit for a new question

Comment: Yes, I do understand and I like it much better what I had before but I need to understand how to edit values in each column before dumping them in the output file.  I do know how to do it the dirty way by splitting the `$current_line`, however,  I'm trying to learn how to program the correct way. I’m trying to learn on my own here.  I will post this question. I’m very grateful for your advice.