# occurance of a blank row in text file after the insertion of a header row

Tags: perl

I would like to insert custom headers to each .tsv file, parse the content of each file and append to the final variant file. I've tried to accomplish this in one loop but it doesn't work, so I've tried two separate loops. The first loop inserts the header into each .tsv file fine, however, the second loop replaces the inserted header with a blank row.  Could someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix this? Thanks

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $home="/data/";                                                     
my $tsv_directory = $home."test_all_runs/".$ARGV[0];
my $tsvfiles = $home."test_all_runs/".$ARGV[0]."/tsv_files.txt";

my @run_directory = (); @run_directory = split /\//, $tsv_directory; print "The run directory is #############".$run_directory[3]."\n";

my $cmd = `ls $tsv_directory/FOCUS*\.tsv > $tsvfiles`; #print "$cmd";
my $cmda = "ls $tsv_directory/FOCUS*\.tsv > $tsvfiles"; #print "$cmda";

my @tsvfiles =();
#this code opens the vcf_files.txt file and passes each line into an array for indidivudal manipulation
open(TXT2, "$tsvfiles");
        while (<TXT2>){  
                push (@tsvfiles, $_);   
                }
close(TXT2);

foreach (@tsvfiles){
        chop($_);
}
#this loop works fine
for my $tsv_file (@tsvfiles){

    $tsv_file =~ m|([^/]+)-oncomine.tsv$| or die "Can't extract Sample ID";
    my $sample_id = $1;
    print "The sample ID is ############## $sample_id\n";
    my $headerline = $run_directory[3]."/".$sample_id;
   my $cmd9 = `sed -i '1i$headerline' $tsv_file`; print $cmd9;#local @ARGV = ($tsv_file);  
}

my $final_variants = $home."test_all_runs/".$ARGV[0]."/final_variant_file.txt";
open my $out_fh, '>', $final_variants or die qq{Unable to open "$final_variants" for output: $!};

my @tsv_files_new = glob $tsv_directory."/FOCUS*.tsv";

##this loop unintentionally replaces the newly inserted header with a blank line.
for my $tsv_file_new ( @tsv_files_new ) {

    print "The current VCF is ############# $tsv_file_new\n";

    $tsv_file_new =~ m|([^/]+)-oncomine.tsv$| or die "Can't extract Sample ID";
    my $sample_id = $1;
    print "The sample ID is ############## $sample_id\n";

    open my $in_fh, '<', $tsv_file_new
            or die qq{Unable to open "$tsv_file_new" for input: $!};

    while ( <$in_fh> ) {

        next if /^#/;
        next if /\b(?:CNV|intronic|synonymous|utr_3|utr_5)\b/;
        next if /\b(?:FORMAT.1.FSRF)\b/;# remove the original headers from Ion Reporter.

        my @fields = split;
        next if ($fields[70] =~ m|([0.])/\1|);
        my $chr = $fields[9]."check";

        my @wanted = ( 10, 21, 67, 68, 70, 77, 78, 81, 83, 84, 88, 92, 98, 100 );
        my $current_line = join "\t", @fields[@wanted];
        my $current_final_line = $sample_id."\t".$chr."\t".$current_line;
        print $out_fh $current_final_line, "\n";
    }
}
exit;
```

Comment: Hello. That looks like my code! What have you tried? You should post the whole of the program that you are using and ask for help, but your thinking is wrong. You came from using multiple files and shell commands to one Perl program, and you just need to change how you build `$current_line` before printing it. Altering after it has been written is the wrong idea

Comment: I see you split your program into problems that concern a single line and ask new question for every problem. All those problems can be solved by learning the language as the problems are not difficult to code. For you, it might be better if you describe your whole problem instead of asking in a step-by-step manner.

Comment: @Borodin There is nothing wrong with your code. I'm just trying to learn how to accomplish one thing at a time without making my questions too long and confusing. I had code that was working but I had many intermediate file but now that I'm learning there is a better way I have figure out the whole process from scratch. I've used `my $cmd9 = `sed -i '1i$SampleID[4]' $Controldata`; print $cmd9;` to add first line to each and it worked but now I need to be able to insert a custom header in the while loop somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my $tsv_file = 'test.txt';

tie my @textFile, 'Tie::File', $tsv_file, recsep => "\n"  or die $!;
for my $line (@textFile) {
    $line = "New Sample\n" if($line =~ /FORMAT\.1\.FSRF/);
}
untie @textFile;
```

Comment: It made an empty line without text "New Sample". I'm trying to manipulate the first line for each sample so I can display sample related info. Your code almost worked but I don't see "New Sample" just a empty line.  Thanks Andrey.

Comment: Yeah I think that's because the data in the file hasn't been written yet. This follows [*Duplicated output with for each loop*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978686/duplicated-output-with-for-each-loop)

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you can replace AAA with BBB

```
$string =~ s/AAA/BBB/;
```

So if you want to:

```
#replace lines containing "FORMAT.1.FSRF" with "New Sample"
```

then try:

```
$string =~ s/FORMAT\.1\.FSRF/New Sample/g;
```

Remove the last `g` if you want to make a single replacement only for each line.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the header rows and replace them with a custom made header specific to each file. Only header rows contain "FORMAT.1.FSRF" therefore I'm using it as a search string. Thanks